# how to change the background color of checkbox?

Tags: jquery

CSS:

```
#partoption2 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF0000;
    height: 16px;
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="parttwo" id="partoption2" value="206365-KT:" >manoji
```

Hi Friends here I need background color of the checkbox to be green and while I check it should go red when I uncheck. Can anyone give me a solution?

http://jsfiddle.net/5txp5g5u/1/

Comment: If your are using CSS3 use the selector ':checked' like this #partoption2:checked

Comment: I suggest hide this checkbox and use sprite map instead, you will have same looking checkbox across all browsers and OS'es. It's bad idea to style form elements, because you will face lots of problems (mac and windows, FF, Chrome, Safari, IE and other browsers).

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/5txp5g5u/12/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style checkbox using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css)

Comment: You cannot alter the look & feel of check box & radio button, but you can do some thing like this :http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/09/custom-checkbox-set/, http://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/BiHzp

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar not this i need the "checkbox" to change the color.

Comment: @mycholan [of course you can](http://www.css3.com/implementing-custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons-with-css3/)

Comment: @yuvi you can with custom plugin ( which will hide the default checkbox and display image based one ) ( we cannot style default checkbox ).

Comment: @yuvi : i should have visited your link. lol..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://codepen.io/dcdev/full/toBzb/

Green when unchecked, red when checked..  This works by actually hiding the default checkbox and styling the label over to of the hidden checkbox to look like a checkbox.

```
label {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s ease-out 1s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1s ease-out 1s;
    -o-transition: background-color 1s ease-out 1s;
    transition: background-color 1s ease-out 1s;
}

.checkbox_red input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s ease-out 1s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1s ease-out 1s;
    -o-transition: background-color 1s ease-out 1s;
    transition: background-color 1s ease-out 1s;
}

.checkbox_red label:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    background: transparent;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    transform: rotate(-50deg);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
.checkbox_red input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.checkbox_red input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);    
}
```

and the html

```
<div class="checkbox_red">
  <input type="checkbox" value="none" id="checkbox_red1" name="check">
  <label for="checkbox_red1"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. i hope you will get a solution for your problem.

```
******html
<p><input type="checkbox" name="1" class="styled green"/> (green)</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="2" class="styled red" checked/> (red)</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="3" class="styled purple" /> (purple)</p>

********javascript

$(function() {

    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        var span = $('<span class="' + $(this).attr('type') + ' ' + $(this).attr('class') + '"></span>').click(doCheck).mousedown(doDown).mouseup(doUp);
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            span.addClass('checked');
        }
        $(this).wrap(span).hide();
    });

    function doCheck() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
            $(this).removeClass('checked');
            $(this).children().prop("checked", false);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('checked');
            $(this).children().prop("checked", true);
        }
    }

    function doDown() {
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
    }

    function doUp() {
        $(this).removeClass('clicked');
    }
});


****css

.checkbox, .radio {
    width: 19px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url("http://i48.tinypic.com/raz13m.jpg");
    display: block;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
 }

.checked {
     background-position: 0px -50px;   
}

.clicked {
     background-position: 0px -25px;
}

.clicked.checked {
     background-position: 0px -75px;
}


.green {
    background-color: green;
 }

 .red {
    background-color: red;
 }

.purple {
    background-color: purple;
 }
```